# aggregating information from two different levels in one query

Tags: sql, hive

I was wondering if it is possible to aggregate information at two different levels using only one query?
For example I have table  and want to get the unique number of customers who bought a certain item and also number of certain item_id each customer_id buys divided by the total number of customers.

```
Table
customer_id   item_id    bought_date
   abc           12        2017-01-01
   def           23        2017-01-08
   abc           12        2017-01-02
   abc           13        2017-01-02
   ghi           23        2017-01-02
```

I want the output

```
item_id   customer_id   item_count_per_customer customers_probability_per_item total_customers
 12         abc               2                      1        3
 13         abc               1                      1        3
 23         def               1                      2        3
 23         ghi               1                      2.
```

I can get the individual column item_count_per_customer as follows:

```
select item_id, customer_id, count(1) as item_count_per_customer
from table
group by item_id, customer_id
```

I can also get the individual column customers_count_per_item as follows:
    select item_id, count(distinct customer_id) as customers_count_per_item
    from table 
    group by item_id

I also need the total unique customer count as follows:
   select count(distinct customer_id) as total_customers from table

So I need all this information in one row. The only way to do this is to combine these 3 queries (perhaps as subqueries) or is there a more efficient way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window functions

```
select      item_id
           ,customer_id
           ,count(*)                                                as item_count_per_customer 
           ,count(distinct customer_id) over (partition by item_id) as customers_count_per_item
           ,count(distinct customer_id) over()                      as total_customers

from        mytable

group by    item_id
           ,customer_id
;
```

---

```
+---------+-------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| item_id | customer_id | item_count_per_customer | customers_count_per_item | total_customers |
+---------+-------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| 23      | ghi         | 1                       | 2                        | 3               |
+---------+-------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| 23      | def         | 1                       | 2                        | 3               |
+---------+-------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| 13      | abc         | 1                       | 1                        | 3               |
+---------+-------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| 12      | abc         | 2                       | 1                        | 3               |
+---------+-------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: What you see here is a copy-paste from an executed code, so the answer is - "Yes". In any case you should test it on your own system, with your own Hive version.